# Is it okay to have pointers to old state objects in React Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, copy, state

I have a react app using redux with a state object that looks like this:

```
{
    personal: { firstName: 'Lance', lastName: 'Uppercut' },
    phones: [
        { id: 1, number: '111-222-3333' },
        { id: 2, number: '444-555-6666' }
    ]
}
```

Say that an action occurred that changed only the `personal` property, leaving `phones` alone. Do I have to copy the entire `phones` array in the reducer or is it okay to leave it pointing to the old array since it did not change?

In other words, is this okay?

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
    personal: { firstName: 'Rock', lastName: 'Strongo' },
    phones: state.phones
});
```

or do I have to copy the array too?

```
return Object.assign({}, {
    personal: { firstName: 'Rock', lastName: 'Strongo' },
    phones: state.phones.map(p => Object.assign({}, p))
});
```

This would also apply to object references. If `phones` where a nested object like this

```
{
    personal: { firstName: 'Lance', lastName: 'Uppercut' },
    phones: {
        '1': { number: '111-222-3333', areaCode: '619' },
        '2': { number: '444-555-6666', areaCode: '512' }
    }
}
```

is it okay to lave the new state object pointing to a reference of the old one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update only what changed, and it's containing structures.

Since state already includes `phones`, and it haven't, you only need to merge in the changed personal:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
    personal: { firstName: 'Rock', lastName: 'Strongo' }
});
```

Or using [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals):

```
return {
    ...state,
    personal: { firstName: 'Rock', lastName: 'Strongo' }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to create a new copy of the state and only change the field you want to change, or namely:

`return {
    ...state,
    personal: { firstName: 'Rock', lastName: 'Strongo' }
});`

(This is usage of the spread operator of es6, which returns a new copy of the state object and changes only the `personal` field, which is shorter and cleaner than the old `Object.assign` way).